# Adding to a variable inside a loop

Tags: python

```
previous_num = 0
sum = 0

def num_update():
add_num = current_num - previous_num
    if add_num > 0:
        sum += add_num
        previous_num = current_num
    elif add_num < 0:
        previous_num = current_num
```

current_num usually increases but sometimes decreases to a lower number than previous.

It's only updating the first element in the list.

```
list = [a, b, c, d]
for i in list:
    num_update()
```

Comment: create a variable outside the loop and pass that variable to function

Comment: I don't see `current_num` getting set.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate what you're trying to do here? We need context as to what you're trying to achieve.

Face-off, here are a few problems I've spotted though.

```
previous_num = 0
sum = 0

def num_update():
  add_num = current_num - previous_num
  if add_num > 0:
    sum += add_num
    previous_num = current_num
  elif add_num < 0:
    previous_num = current_num
```

You were missing the indentation for the first line of your definition

In your for i... list iteration,

You should be using it in the following format:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
  //code
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue, if you want to iterate through a list, you need to use the length of the list.

Comment: `You should be using [your for i... list iteration] in the following [way]:` how do you reach that conclusion? In the code presented, `i` isn't used.

Comment: Thanks to all for their input. I found the problem. I was resetting previous_num at the end of the loop without consideration for the other elements in the list.